# Copy paste in the Javascript is not using the SWF, and that would have been cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, copy-paste

I wanted to ask you how to do copy paste the javascript or jquery and that they acted without the SWF file. I'm working on a browser is not installed flash, so you have to do without it, here's how to do it. And so what would it cross browser. There is good discussion on this subject but there I have not found an answer for yourself, here is the link [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript).

Comment: Most browsers have a setting that disables clipboard functions - in that case the scripts will not be working anyway

Comment: You're right, but I do not want to take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in general to access the clipboard from JavaScript running in a browser. Some browsers allow it if the user has enabled a security preference, but by default these preferences are switched off. Without the limited access you get with something written in Flash like [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) (which only lets you copy to the clipboard but not from it), it's impossible.